# Unable to extract first row from CSV file filtered by a specific header

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a csv file that contains data like below:

```
account,id,name
1234,a3bu5,test
12,b4cf8,test
789,t4wy7,test2
```

I need to filter by the **name** header and extract all **account** numbers into an array.

In my current code, I am iterating through multiple names and want to store their account numbers in separate arrays. (i.e. (1234,12) and (789) in this example)

Example Code (select header):

```
$namesToParse = @("test")
$inputFile = "output.csv"
$testArray = @()
$csvFile = Import-csv $inputFile
For ($i = 0; $i-le $namesToParse.length-1; $i++) {
    (" - Getting account numbers for '{0}'`n" -f ($namesToParse[$i]) ) | write-host -ForegroundColor Blue
    #SELECT HEADER
    $csv = $csvFile | Select-String -Pattern $namesToParse[$i] | select $csvFile.account | Out-String
}

$testArray = $csv.split(",")
$testArray[0]
```

Example Code (select line):

```
$namesToParse = @("test")
$inputFile = "output.csv"
$testArray = @()
$csvFile = Import-csv $inputFile
For ($i = 0; $i-le $namesToParse.length-1; $i++) {
    (" - Getting account numbers for '{0}'`n" -f ($namesToParse[$i]) ) | write-host -ForegroundColor Blue
    #SELECT LINE
    $csv = $csvFile | Select-String -Pattern $namesToParse[$i] | select line | Out-String
}

$testArray = $csv.split(",")
$testArray[0]
```

I am aware that the issue is coming from my csv variable, but I am not sure what to use to display my results. The closest examples that I have found online involve selecting the account header as shown above, but this ignores the pattern that filters by name and displays all account numbers. If I use **select line** instead of account the pattern works, but all values are received I am left with more data than I require. This adds extra steps to the script that I am hoping to eliminate.

What is the best way to retrieve the information that I need, or am I piping this information incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, you seem to overcomplicate things.

- `Import-csv` to read data in
- `Format-Table` with the -GroupBy parameter

---

```
> Import-Csv .\output.csv | Format-Table account -GroupBy name


   name: test

account
-------
1234
12


   name: test2

account
-------
789
```

---

Another way to gather accounts per name with `Group-Object`

```
Import-Csv .\output.csv | Select-Object account,name | 
    Group-Object name | ForEach-Object {
        "{0,15}:{1}" -f $_.name,($_.group.account -join ',')}
```

---

```
       test:1234,12
      test2:789
```

Or crete a new table from that information

```
$NewTable =  Import-Csv .\output.csv | Select-Object account,name |
     Group-Object name | ForEach-Object {
         [PSCustomObject]@{
             'Name'     = $_.name
             'Accounts' = ($_.group.account -join ',')
          }
      }
$NewTable
```

---

```
Name  Accounts
----  --------
test  1234,12
test2 789
```

Comment: Appreciate the simplicity. To get this as a multidimensional array I will still need to jump through a few hoops, but it should be fairly simple from here.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks pretty complicated, you can solve the problem in a more readable way using `ForEach` loops:

```
$namesToParse = @("test")
$inputFile = "output.csv"
$csvFile = Import-csv $inputFile

$ht = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable

# Loop over each row in the csv file, assigning the row to a variable called $row
ForEach ($row in $csvFile) {
    $match = $false
    # Set a new variable containing the name value (for readability)
    $nameValue = $row.name
    # iterate over the namesToParse array, checking for matches
    ForEach ($name in $namesToParse) {
        # If a match is found, set the boolean variable $match to true
        if ($nameValue -match $name) {
            $match = $true
        }
    }
    # If there was a match, get the account numbers
    if ($match) {
        (" - Getting account numbers for '{0}'`n" -f ($row.name) ) | write-host -ForegroundColor Blue
        # We are collecting records into a hashtable, e.g. $ht.test2
        # So, if the $ht.test2 entry doesn't already exist, create it as a blank array
        if (-not $ht.$nameValue) {
            $ht.$nameValue = @()
        }
        # Add the account number to the array
        $ht.$nameValue += $row.account
    }
}

# Display results
$ht
```

1. Loop over the rows of the CSV file
2. Go through each entry of namesToParse and check for matches in the name column
3. If there is a match, check if the hash entry has been created for that name value (e.g. $ht.test2), if not, then create a new empty array to add account numbers to
4. If there's a match and the array already exists, just append to it.

Comment: I was hoping to keep my program a bit more concise, but this does work well other than outputting the account number i am working with twice.
Accepted LotPing's as I can simplify the logic with the multidimensional array down to about 3 lines of code.